# Can't use VB Script to create registry keys

Tags: vbscript, registry, wmi

I can't use VB Script to create registry keys.  I've hecked WMI using wbemtest and I am running the script using administrative privileges.  I beleive the code is correct - I've seen several sample on the internet and it seems to be straight forward.  Is there anything else within the OS that could prevent a VB Script from creating registry keys?

Sample code is below.

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

strComputer = "ostslhqe-48958" 

Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\TestKey"

objRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Script Center"

objRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of registry entry creation would be:

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strValueName = "My DWORD Value"
dwValue = 13
objRegistry.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strValueName, dwValue
```

Source :  http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/11/16/how-can-i-create-a-new-registry-key.aspx

Comment: Your example uses a variable that doesn't get assigned - strKeyPath.  I'll assume that this variable should be assigned the value of the key that should be created.  In this case, I don't see the difference in the code you posted from my example.  Other than i mistakenly assigned my computer name to the strComputer variable.

Comment: After reviewing my script I see that in the function CreateKey I specified HKEY_CURRENT_USER, which was not defined.  I should've been using HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE which is assigned &H80000002.  Thanks for your assistance.